# a .bat file that opens the command promt and enters text values into the promt

Tags: batch-file

I have been here before and found answers to many a question but I'm coming up blank here, or maybe its just my limited understanding.  Anyway I have crafted a `.bat` file that opens the cmd as admin

```
start ""/b 
C:\Users\"my username"\Desktop\cmdadmin.lnk
```

through a shortcut on my desk top but thats all I've got, what I want is a `.bat` file that opens the cmd as admin, enters this line

```
cd C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVSMI\
```

then this line

```
nvidia-smi -ac 3505,1392
```

This will set my gpu and its memory clock to the desired speeds, I just don't want to do it manually every time the machine shuts down because these values reset each time.  I would also like to be able to edit it as these values may change.  If you could explain how this works too that would be a plus as I would like to be able to do it (in theory anyway) should I ever change the brand of cards and or the directory changes.

If you have a more elegant way to solve this by all means I'm open to suggestion.

environment windows 10

Comment: This is a perfect opportunity to [learn more about](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748993(v=ws.11).aspx) the [Task Scheduler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Alright, it may be uncouth to answer ones own question but I was able to hunt down this little gem of code and it worked, not quite the learning experience I was hoping for but all of this would have taken ages to learn and I have mining to do.

@Compo, you were absolutely right I had no idea what task scheduler did until you mentioned it.  I will set this to run automatically upon log in so I never have to think about it again.

If you don't want to verify with your eye that the commands were successfully executed remove the pause at the end and it will be but a blip and done. I just wanted to see that it worked.

```
    REM  --> Check for permissions
    >nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"

    REM --> If error flag set, we do not have admin.
    if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
        echo Requesting administrative privileges...
        goto UACPrompt
    ) else ( goto gotAdmin )

    :UACPrompt
        echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
        set params = %*:"=""
        echo UAC.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/c %~s0 %params%", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

        "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
        del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
        exit /B

    :gotAdmin
        pushd "%CD%"
        CD /D "%~dp0"
    cd C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVSMI\

    nvidia-smi -ac 3505,1392
    pause
```

I Hope this comes in handy for anyone including miners that are looking to streamline nvidia gpu settings or start the command prompt in admin mode.

keep in mind that the listed clock changes may not work for your card. To find the correct settings use this command chain.

```
cd C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVSMI\
nvidia-smi -q -d SUPPORTED_CLOCKS | more
```

This will produce a list of supported clock speeds for the final line of code.   `nvidia-smi -ac 3505,1392`this is "MEMORY,GPU" I selected the highest settings, you can overclock from there at your own peril.